# Do I need +6 Bab to take pummeling style?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, feats

The prerequisites of pummeling style read as follows.

> Prerequisite(s): Improved Unarmed Strike; base attack bonus +6, brawler's flurry class feature, or flurry of blows class feature

Can a normal monk take this at level one? The way the semi-colon is placed leads me to believe I can.

Answer (score 8):

I believe you are correct. Standard grammar rules mean that the list could be rewritten as:

> Prerequisite(s): Improved Unarmed Strike **and either** base attack bonus +6, brawler's flurry class feature, or flurry of blows class feature

Answer (score 5):

You need multiple attacks for this feat to be useful, so it is a prerequisite. Having any of the options listed after Improved Unarmed Strike will qualify for this.

From Pummeling Style:

> Benefit: Whenever you use a full-attack action or flurry of blows to make multiple attacks ...